# Rewrite the following sentences in the passive voice

Tags: syntactic-analysis, passive-voice

I need to rewrite the following sentences in the passive voice.

> 1. If frightened, these animals can discharge a strong smelling fluid from their scent glands under their tails.
> 2. We may define artificial intelligence as the capacity of a computer to imitate human reasoning.

Comment: This question is doomed for closure if you do not show us why you are having difficulty. Have you ever written a sentence in the passive voice before? Is this your first time? Do you know what a passive sentence looks like? Did you try to do this task before asking here? Show us your attempts and we can help you better.

Comment: Yep, you got your answer and now you don't care anymore what happens. -1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

1. If frightened, a strong smelling fluid can be discharged by these animals from the scent glands under their tails.
2. Artificial intelligence may be defined as the capacity of a computer to imitate human reasoning.

In both instances, the object of the active sentence becomes the subject of the passive sentence:

1. Here, "a strong smelling fluid" is the *object*. This becomes the *subject* in the passive mood.
2. Here, "artificial intelligence" is the *object*. This becomes the *subject* in the passive mood.

Comment: Hi! You're new in EL&U town but we tend to avoid answering "homework" questions around here, especially if the asker has shown no effort. To make your answer more useful to future visitors could you explain how to construct a passive sentence?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, Noted for future, thanks.

Comment: And the same principle applies to all questions that are clearly off-topic. Unfortunately, answering them tends to encourage unwanted behavior like it apparently did in this case. So it’s actually better to sometimes curb our “oh, let me just help out quickly” instinct which in general is what makes the SE sites so successful and enjoyable. Sad but true...

Comment: @Stephie, In this situation should I just delete the answer? Apologies, I should have read up more on the rules.

Comment: No need to delete. The answer is not wrong or bad and there is another answer as well. Without any answer, this post would probably be (auto)deleted at some point. Moderators can still choose to do so. So if you learned something about the site, this answer has already a double use ;-)

Answer (score -3):

1. A strong smelling fluid from these animal's scents glands under their tail can be discharge if they are frightened.
2. Artificial intelligence may be defined as the capacity of a computer to imitate human reasoning.

Comment: It's unabashedly identical to jpp's, except your answer  contains an error.

Comment: thanks for ur helping. this was not a home work just I have a doubt about the answers so that's why I asked u.

Comment: @AbdirahmanSaid so let me understand, you're thanking Tien Tran who posted a nearly identical answer to jpp's but which *still* contains an error. Why don't you thank the user who actually spent time answering your question? And gave you the confidence to then post a new question asking to convert five sentences without so much as a please or a thank you. And without showing any effort whatsoever in trying to solve the problem or explaining what they don't understand.